# TFS Project path

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

My requirement is to automatically deploy my  project  in a remote machine. Currently my project resides in the  TFS server.

In my project I have a folder named *Database* and  I used to add the sql scripts to this folder and checked in the complete solution to TFS.  In order to run the script for the remote machine I need to get the latest script from the TFS. So how can get the path of  *Database* folder and associated file (.sql file). I am using tfs api to retrieve the information about project from tfs.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommended using Visual Studio DB professional to do that not just a folder in a source control.

See this post

[How do I share a database with TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826759/how-do-i-share-a-database-with-tfs/6828347#6828347)

but if you still want to do this with your folder you can use Workspace.Get() with appropriate option

```
Workspace.Get()
```

Fore more information see this article

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace.get.aspx

Comment: There is no longer a "Visual Studio DB Professional". That functionality is now part of Visual Studio Premium (maybe also "Professional", I'm not sure).

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Server Data Tools 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg427686) is the latest addition to the Microsoft suite for automatic deployment and synchronization of SQL Schema's.

The Database development tools that ship with Visual Studio are now only part of Visual Studio 2010 Premium and Ultimate.